# $ \varphi(x)$ using the sum of $\theta(x)$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove the following formula: 
 $$ \varphi(x)=\theta(x) + \theta(x^{1/2}) + \theta(x^{1/3})+ \theta(x^{1/4})+...++ \theta(x^{1/m})$$

with $$ m \leq \log(\log(x)) $$
 knowing that
$$\varphi(x)= \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n)= \sum_{p^k \leq x} \log(p) $$
and $$ \theta(x)= \sum_{p \leq x} \log (p) $$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Split the $\varphi$ sum depending on which prime power you are summing over. By the way, $\varphi$ is normally called $\psi$, $\varphi$ is reserved for the euler totient function.

Comment: @Asvin how would you do that?

Comment: i wrote $$ \psi(x)= \sum_{p \leq x} log(P)+ \sum_{p \leq x^{1/2}} log(P)+...+ \sum_{p \leq x^{1/m}} log(P) = \sum_{p \leq x} log(P)+ \sum_{p^2 \leq x} log(P)+...+ \sum_{p^m \leq x} log(P)  $$ but i still do not see the utility of the 'm' who is smaller than log(log(x)) @Asvin